# How can I get the redistributable for Report Viewer to be included with my application?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, setup-project

I've been setting up a new machine for building the deployment packages for some code, using the Setup & Deployment projects within Visual Studio 2008.

When trying to build an existing project that lists "Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Report Viewer" as a prerequisite, I'm getting a warning:

> WARNING: Could not find prerequisite 'Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Report Viewer' in path '%Program Files%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\'

Going into the Prerequisites dialog shows it with a warning overlay with tooltip:

> Prerequisite could not be found for bootstrapping

Looking at previous builds, we've been able to redistribute these alongside our applications in the past although checking the install media, that was deploying version 9.0.30729.1, but the version in 
%program files%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\ReportViewer is 9.0.30729.4402 (which I believe is the redistributable including [the fix for MS09-062](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972222)).

I suspect that there may be some additional steps that I need to do (much like you do for SP1 of v3.5 of the .Net Framework), but I cannot see these documented anywhere? What do I need to do to once again allow the Report Viewer redistibutable to be included with my setup projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears there is a typo in the [Visual Studio 2008 SP1 Readme](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/2/8/a2807f78-c861-4b66-9b31-9205c3f22252/vs2008sp1readme.htm), that says (In section 2.3.1.7):

> Replace the link `http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=98185` with `http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=98185&clcid=0x409` in package.xml.

Instead it should be replaced with:
`http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=98185&amp;clcid=0x409`

This still gives a warning:

> WARNING: The value of the 'PublicKey' attribute in 'Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Report Viewer' does not match that of file '%Program Files%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\ReportViewer\ReportViewer.exe'.

However, it will still be deployed.

**EDIT**

To fix the PublicKey warning, you need to change the link in the ReportViewer/en/Package.xml to be `http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=185122`, and change the PublicKey attribute of the `<PackageFile>` element to match that of the new EXE - to get this (on Windows 7), open the file properties from Exploere, go to the Digital Signatures tab, select the certificate, and choose [ Details ]; Select [ View Certificate ]; on the Details tab, scroll to the Public Key field, and the value displayed below is the public key (you'll want to remove white space).